# What is the best way to visualize the relationship two categorical variables

Tags: clustering, visualization, categorical-data

I am currently working on an ambulance dataset and one of my tasks is to find when a patient was misdiagnosed by the call dispatcher.

I have two codes; a dispatch code(what the dispatcher believes is wrong with the patient) and a hospital code(what a doctor decides the actual diagnosis is in hospital)

I'm looking for a way of visualizing the relationship between the two codes i.e. given ambulance code x what is the probability of each ambulance code being the outcome.

This can be computed using SQL pretty easily but I'm looking for a way to visualize/cluster it would be great. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Some good feedback in the comments

firstly the dimensionality:
Dispatch code can take 1 of 1722 unique values

hospital codes can take 1 of 1058 unique values

The two codes are entirely different an example would be as follows

```
Dispatcher 17D03:Unconscious 
Hospital R41:Other symptoms and signs involving cognitive functions and awareness
```

My interest is in visualizing the relationship. So for example given a dispatcher code of unconscious what are the most common hospital codes?

Again this is fairly easy to calculate numerically but a visualization would make it easier to explain to my stake holders.

Comment: How many unique codes are there? Do hospital and dispatch use the same set of codes? If the answers are "low" and "yes", then a heatmap should be good.

Comment: How many dimensions does it have?

Comment: A *matrix* as in a spreadsheet (columns=dispatch, rows=hospital) certainly seems appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately both codes have high dimensionality and use a different set of codes. Rather than visualising how frequently a code is classified correctly I want to find the commen relationships

for example row in the database is this:

Comment: `Dispatcher 17D03:Unconscious`

   `Hospital R41:Other symptoms and signs involving cognitive functions and awareness`

Comment: I am more interested in visualizing how the dispatch codes map to hospital codes. For example Unconsciousness could map to numerous output codes such as concussion, drunkenness etc

I am curious about which input codes map to which output codes, and how to visualize it.

Comment: My dataset has 1722 unique dispatch codes and 1058 hospital codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up using an alluvial diagram on [rawgraphs.](https://rawgraphs.io/learning/how-to-make-an-alluvial-diagram//)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a confusion matrix to generate the heat map of your data.

Suppose you have:

```
labels = ['cardiac arrest', 'choking', 'seizure']
dispatch_code = ['cardiac arrest', 'choking', 'seizure', 'choking', 'seizure', 'seizure', 'cardiac arrest', 'cardiac arrest']
hospital_code = ['cardiac arrest', 'choking', 'cardiac arrest', 'choking', 'seizure', 'seizure', 'seizure', 'cardiac arrest']
```

Then you can plot with:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cm = confusion_matrix(hospital_code, dispatch_code)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
plt.title('Confusion matrix of the classifier')
fig.colorbar(cax)
ax.set_xticklabels([''] + labels)
ax.set_yticklabels([''] + labels)
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('True')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This example shows that often there is a correct code coming from the dispatcher (yellow stripe in the middle). *Cardiac arrest* and *seizure* are often confused (blue) and *chocking* is never misclassified (purple).

Answer (score 1):

If you are after counts of multi dimensional variables then Mosaicplot can help. In R there is a function from the graphics package called mosaicplot. It's one of base packages that come with R.

> HairEyeColor
>   , , Sex = Male

```
   Eye
```

Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
  Black    32   11    10     3
  Brown    53   50    25    15
  Red      10   10     7     7
  Blond     3   30     5     8

, , Sex = Female

```
   Eye
```

Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
  Black    36    9     5     2
  Brown    66   34    29    14
  Red      16    7     7     7
  Blond     4   64     5     8

> mosiacplot(HairEyeColor)
>   [image]